# XeLaTeX FakeBold produces point at origin of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, fontspec

This is a XeLaTeX question. FontSpec's FakeBold produces an unwanted dot in any tikzpicture. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[FakeBold=0.5]{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The point is at the (0,0) position in the PDF which XeLaTeX produces and can be selected as text. It is rather annoying, as the persistent dot messes up all tikz pictures. If I delete the line

```
\setmainfont[FakeBold=0.5]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

then the point is gone. However, I want to stick to the fake bold Latin Modern Roman font. Is there any workaround to get rid of the point in tikz pictures? (like using fontspec or tikz itself to specify something like "FakeBold=0" in tikz pictures, for example)

People asked me to show how it looks like. This actually made me encounter a strange thing: The point looks different with different pdf viewers. I've chosen FakeBold=200 for the following pictures to make it more ob**vious**:

This is how the (enlarged) point looks like with Okular:

[image]

This is how the (enlarged) point looks with Evince:

[image]

This is how the (enlarged) point looks with the Adobe Acrobat Reader:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any point in my results, could you show it?

Comment: I also don't see any dots when I compile your code.

Comment: Strange... When I compile the code there is clearly a black point. Maybe it depends on the pdf viewer? (I see the point with both okular and evince.) Try FakeBold=200 to make the point bigger. At that size it is actually a large black square standing at one of its corners (like a diamond shape). How can I show it to you? (I'm not an expert with stackexchange.)

Comment: Also with `FakeBold = 200` I see no dots - not in Adobe Reader and not in Evince. You probably need to tell us more about your TeX distribution and your OS.

Comment: The first line of xelatex --version reads: XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012) My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: I've found a workaround: adding \filldraw[white] (0,0) circle (3pt); as the first command in the tikzpicture environment hides the black dot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is almost certainly due to outdated software and the OP found a (not great, in my view) workaround over 2 years ago. No activity since that date (except spam and my comments, as I didn't check the date first).